# How to reverse order of blocks of text

Tags: bash, sorting, text

How can I revert the order of some blocks of text using only bash commands like sed and cat? What I want is something like tac, but instead of operating line by line, it would operate block by block. Example:

**From**

```
/Section 3/
Rabbits
Dogs
Cats

/Section 2/
Eagles
Mice

/Section 1/
Dogs
Rabbits
Lemmings
```

**To**

```
/Section 1/
Dogs
Rabbits
Lemmings

/Section 2/
Eagles
Mice

/Section 3/
Rabbits
Dogs
Cats
```

In some files, the beginning of the block is marked by a slash, as in the example above. In others, the blocks are marked only by the existence of one or more blank lines between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `emacs`, you can use the `sort-paragraphs` command:

<kbd>Ctrl-x</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>Meta-x</kbd><kbd>sort-paragraphs</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

In `vim`: https://superuser.com/questions/365094/sort-file-per-paragraph-in-vim

---

Use the basic unix tools:

```
awk -F'\n' -vRS='' -vOFS=',' '{$1=$1}1' input.txt |
    sort |
        tr ',' '\n' |
            sed 's@^/@\n/@'
```

I use `awk` to transform the data to a `csv`, then `sort` the `csv`, at last I transform the `csv` back to list style.

---

#### result:

```
/Section 1/
Dogs
Rabbits
Lemmings

/Section 2/
Eagles
Mice

/Section 3/
Rabbits
Dogs
Cats
```

---

**Edit**: Sorry, I didn't look at your question very carefully. You can change the `sort` command to `tac` to reverse the order.

Comment: Doesn't this sort and not reverse as OP asks?

Comment: oh. I misunderstood the question.

Comment: The last 'sed' (which depends on how blocks start) can be omitted by adding -vROS=',\n' to the original awk command.

Comment: The `awk`/etc command does not work if the file contains commas. And replacing the comma in the command by a rare character such as ĵ makes it insert empty lines.

Comment: The `emacs` method sorts instead of reversing, you may want to remove it or create a separate question/answer for it. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 4):

If there are blank lines separating all blocks,

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS RS;RS=""}{a[NR]=$0}END{for(i=NR;i>0;i--)print a[i]}'
```

Comment: Best solution for me/ for anyone who needs a simple order change that doesn't depend on the headings (I suppose that's why the accepted answer didn't work for my example)

Answer (score 1):

Use `csplit` to split them into separate files, put the generated filenames into another file, then use `tac` to get the filenames to merge.

Comment: `csplit file.txt /\n\n/` fails with `csplit: ‘/nn/’: match not found` unfortunately.

Comment: `csplit all /^$/` creates two files: xx00 contains section 3, and xx01 contains sections 2 and 1, even though separating lines contain zero character though. Would you mind giving the full command?

Answer (score 1):

What separates blocks in your example? 2 newlines. In Emacs Lisp, if the text is in a string, if you install [`dash`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) and [`s`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el), you can use one of these 2 equivalent expressions:

```
(s-join "\n\n" (nreverse (s-split "\n\n" s))) ; where s is your string
(->> s (s-split "\n\n") nreverse (s-join "\n\n"))
```

[`->>`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#threading-macros-1) is a dash's threading macro, which pulls `s` through successive function invocations. Think [*nix pipes](http://xahlee.info/comp/unix_pipes_and_functional_lang.html): `s | s-split "\n\n" | nreverse | s-join "\n\n"`.

If you want to have an Emacs Lisp function that opens a file, reverses the blocks then saves it back to the same files, you could also install [f](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el) file manipulation library:

```
(defun reverse-blocks (f)
  "F is a filename."
  (interactive "fFind file: ") ; letter `f` is filename goes in first arg
  (let ((s (f-read f))) ; read file into a string
    (--> s
         s-chomp ; remove trailing newline
         (s-split "\n\n" it)
         nreverse
         (s-join "\n\n" it)
         (f-write it 'utf-8 f)))) ; write to the same file
```

Here I use another trailing macro [`-->`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#---x-form-rest-more), which allows to put the result of the previous computation in argument denoted `it` of the next computation. E.g. if the result of `nreverse` is `X`, then the equivalent would be `(s-join "\n\n" X)`. Finally, suppose you not just want to reverse, but to sort your blocks based on the number after word “Section”:

```
(--sort (< (string-to-number (cadr (s-match "/.*?\\([0-9]\\)/" it)))
           (string-to-number (cadr (s-match "/.*?\\([0-9]\\)/" other))))
        it) ; put it instead of nreverse
```

Which, using [`dash-functional`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#function-combinators-1) is equivalent to:

```
(--sort (-on '<
             (-compose 'string-to-number
                       'cadr
                       (-partial 's-match "/.*?\\([0-9]+\\)/")))
        it) ; put it instead of nreverse
```

Read `dash` documentation to understand, what [`-on`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-on-operator-transformer), [`-compose`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-on-operator-transformer), [`-partial`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-partial-fn-rest-args) do.